# Is there only a finite amount of primes that differ by $2k \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-gaps

With $2k \in \mathbb N$ greater or equal to the bound in Yitang Zhang's proof about prime number gaps (I put it that way since it's constantly decreasing).

As far as I know the proof states that there are infinitely many primes which differ by an even number lesser than the bound. Does that mean that there are only finitely many that differ by an even number greater or equal to the bound?

Edit:

The proof stated in the beginning: There are infinitely many primes that differ by a number less that 70 million. Now the (collective) proof states that there are infinitely many primes that differ by a number less than 246. Does that mean that the numbers between 246 and 70 million are excluded from being the distance of infinitely many prime pairs? (And also the ones above 70M ofc.)

Comment/answer by AndréNicolas:

They are not excluded. There is an old conjecture ([Polignac's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac's_conjecture)) that **for every** $k$ there are infinitely primes that differ by $2k$. That conjecture may very well be correct. It is now known that there is **at least** one $k$ such that there are infinitely primes that differ by $2k$, and that in fact there is such a $k$ with $k \leq 123$.

Comment: I don't see how that would follow. Infinitely many even integers differ by 2, but it doesn't follow that only finitely many differ by more than 2.

Comment: @coffeemath So the twin prime number theorem is already proven?

Comment: No I didn't say that, only that it can't be decided just from Zhang's result.

Comment: No.There are arbitrarily large gaps. Consider for n>1 that n!+s for 1<s< n+1 is greater than s and divisible by s.  We can also deduce the existence of arbitrarily large  gaps by knowing that the asymptotic density  of the primes is 0: If P(n) is the number of primes less than n then P(n)/n goes to 0 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @user254665 I know that. My question refers to the amount of primes that differ by a fixed number.

Comment: @coffeemath Well the proof uses a bound, but maybe the proof's layout is more complex in this regard.

Comment: The  first of these recent theorems is that if p(n) is the n-th prime then there are  infinitely many n for which p(n+1)-p(n)<70,000,000. So there exists at least one  k<70.000.000  for which there are infinitely many n satisfying p(n+1)-p(n)=k.

Answer (score 1):

You argue that because an infinite amount of numbers have some property, therefore a finite amount of numbers do not have that property.

That is not true; for example an infinite amount of integers are even, but there are also an infinite amount of odd integers.

Comment: no it doesn't mean that.  it just  means what it says

Comment: They are not excluded. There is an old conjecture that **for every** $k$ there are infinitely primes that differ by $2k$. That conjecture may very well be correct. It is now known that there is **at least** one $k$ such that there are infinitely primes that differ by $2k$, and that in fact there is such a $k$ with $k\le 123$.

Comment: (For those interested in that old conjecture, it is [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture)

Comment: You are welcome. The recent results are a major achievement, but for almost all $k$, the problem remains open. And we do not even know precisely the $k$ for which the problem has been settled!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is there anywhere to read up on the results? Does Zhangs breakthrough somehow say anything about more than one $k$ or something related?

Comment: There is the original paper, and also lots of stuff on the Internet. I do not know anything specific about extensions. But there are undoubtedly papers being written now.